# Stop Salesforce Standard UI Phone Number field formatting (on blur)

Tags: javascript, contact

I would like to stop Salesforce from formatting phone number fields on blur when editing contact records through the standard UI.

If I enter a mobile number (e.g. 0400 000 000) into the edit UI for contact (standard not custom VF page) and click away (on blur) Javascript fires and changes the format to (040) 000-0000.

Can i stop this from happening without replacing the edit page with a custom VF page? I really don't want to go to all that effort of coding one when it seems like such a small client-side change...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a + at the beginning of a number to prevent automatic formatting. There isn't a reliable way to prevent this automatic formatting otherwise without code. For exaample +41251351415 will remain that way when you leave the field. This is noted in the documentation.

Comment: While it is not a perfect solution you are right - this is the Salesforce recommended solution. Thank you